# Default values in input fields disappeared

Tags: javascript, catalogsearch, forms, newsletter, ce-1.9.2.1

I've noticed that the default values for the catalog search and newsletter subscription have disappeared.

I have checked form.mini.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Search entire store here...') ?>');
    searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
//]]>
</script>
```

and subscribe.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
    new Varien.searchForm('newsletter-validate-detail', 'newsletter', '<?php echo $this->helper('newsletter')->__('Enter your email address') ?>');
//]]>
</script>
```

However I haven't changed anything on this. I'm guessing it's some sort of .js conflict?

Comment: Check browser console to find some kind of Js error. You can use a placeholder on input too, like @Henry's Cat said.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of how this is broken, we are not in 2008 any more (when Magento was born), and, nowadays there is this thing called HTML5. It comes with placeholders for form elements. You may want to re-factor your theme so that the templates use the HTML 5 placeholder, e.g.

```
<input placeholder="Search entire store here..." ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

check your app.js and comment out below like so. If you wish to remove the validation script.

```
/** Varien.searchForm.prototype.initialize = function (form, field, emptyText) {

this.form = $(form);
this.field = $(field);
this.emptyText = emptyText;

Event.observe(this.form, 'submit', this.submit.bind(this));
Event.observe(this.field, 'change', this.change.bind(this));
Event.observe(this.field, 'focus', this.focus.bind(this));
Event.observe(this.field, 'blur', this.blur.bind(this));
this.blur();
}


Varien.searchForm.prototype.submit = function (event) {
if (this.field.value == this.emptyText || this.field.value == ''){
    Event.stop(event);
    this.field.addClassName('validation-failed');
    this.field.focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
}

Varien.searchForm.prototype.change = function (event) {
if (
    this.field.value != this.emptyText
    && this.field.value != ''
    && this.field.hasClassName('validation-failed')
) {
    this.field.removeClassName('validation-failed');
}
}

Varien.searchForm.prototype.blur = function (event) {
if (this.field.hasClassName('validation-failed')) {
    this.field.removeClassName('validation-failed');
}
} **/
```